# How to embed PDF in Excel not as icon?

Tags: excel, pdf

I have the following code to embed PDF into Excel:

```
ImagePDF = "\\Path\fileName.pdf"
Worksheets("sheet1").OLEObjects.Add Filename:=ImagePDF, link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

This code has been working correctly until a few days ago. Now, instead of embedding the PDF files it show an icon

I'm guessing the problem is not Excel, but something in Windows.

Any ideas what could be causing the issue?

Comment: What happens when you try as a user? My best guess would be that OLE Server software is no longer available / registered in Windows, so the file content can't be processed and displayed.

Comment: Doing it manually in Excel it works actually. Just tested it.

Comment: Does recording that in a macro show any (significant) differences between your code and the recorded code? If you double-click the icon the current code creates does it work?

Comment: I resolved the problem by running > Help > Repair in Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

I initially resolved this issue by running in Adobe Reader -> Help > Repair

I found afterwards that the problem re-appeared and this solution didn't work anymore

I resolved it finally by running in Adobe Reader -> Edit > Preferences > General > Select As Default PDF Handler

[image: Adobe Reader print screen]